# How to define a Gaussian voting for generalized hough transform within a range of displacement of a coordinate in accumulator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

I am not professional programmer and taking baby steps in that. I have defined a Gaussian kernel which shows the weights for scoring with a window size of 5 and `sigma=3` (i.e., 3 displacements) in python.

```
[[0.00364954 0.01483356 0.02344521 0.01483356 0.00364954]
 [0.01483356 0.06029105 0.09529314 0.06029105 0.01483356]
 [0.02344521 0.09529314 0.15061577 0.09529314 0.02344521]
 [0.01483356 0.06029105 0.09529314 0.06029105 0.01483356]
 [0.00364954 0.01483356 0.02344521 0.01483356 0.00364954]]
```

This is the plot of Gaussian:

[image]

If `c_i` is the center cell of Gaussian window, the weights should be like the following:
[image]

where `delta_p` show the displacement from the `c_i`, How can I find the neighbors and then add the Gaussian weights to those neighbors, in which their indices are ranging from -2 to 2 from left to right and from top to bottom?

**Indeed, I do not understand how to include this in accumulator increment?**

Comment: maybe these help:  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter && https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the equation there. If `c_i = (i, j, k)` is the center cell in the Hough space `S`, and normally you'd just increase `S[i, j, k] += 1`, now you do:

```
S[i + di, j + dj, k + dk] += exp( -(di**2 + dj**2 + dk**2)/(2*(sigma**2)) )
```

for all values of `di`, `dj` and `dk` in the range [-2,2].

Of course, you would use the pre-computed values for speed. I'm sure you can use slicing in some way:

```
S[i-2:i+3, j-2:j+3, k-2:k+3] = S[i-2:i+3, j-2:j+3, k-2:k+3] + gauss_weights
```

To avoid having to check for out-of-bounds indexing in the above (which complicates code and slows things down) I recommend that you expand your Hough space by two cells on all sides. If you need periodic boundary conditions (e.g. for the angle axis) then you can, after computing the Hough space, take the 2-cell margin on either side of that dimension and add it to the opposite side:

```
S[:, :, 2:4] = S[:, :, 2:4] + S[:, :, -2:]
S[:, :, -4:-2] = S[:, :, -4:-2] + S[:, :, 0:2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, It is very helpful. Could I ask what is `k` third dimension here, that you have brought?
 
the other question is that how can I define the accumulator when I am including rotation and scaling into the Hough transform?

Comment: @S.EB: I didn't know how many dimensions your Hough space has, so I wrote this with three dimensions. It can by any number of dimensions. To include scaling and rotation, add a dimension for scaling and a dimension for rotation to the Hough space. Choosing the sampling density for these dimensions is quite difficult, I think.